# Is there a way to avoid the default git user in the ssh config?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have 2 github accounts in the same computer, I want to be able to provide the user with which I wish to authenticate (i.e `ssh userA@github` or `ssh userB@github`). This works fine with the following .ssh/config file:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname github.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile .ssh\userA_key
  User userA
Host github.com
  Hostname github.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile .ssh\userB_key
  User userB
```

However, if I authenticate with the *git* user (i.e. `ssh git@github.com`). I get a successfully authenticated message with the user that appears first in the config file (userA). Is there a way to prevent this? I want to provide either userA or userB, and not being able to authenticate as *git* user.

Comment: You only ever authenticate as `git@github.com`. You are identified by the ssh key you present, not the username.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+%5Bssh%5D+multiple+accounts

Answer (score 4):

If you are using GitHub, you need to always used the `git` user.  GitHub, like many other places that provide Git hosting, always uses the user `git` and then determines the identity of the user based on the SSH key provided.

So if you use userA's SSH key with the `git` user, then GitHub will think you're userA, and if you use userB's SSH key with the `git` user, then GitHub will think you're userB.  There's no need to identify yourself by the username.

In some other hosting environments, such as when using Gitolite or other self-hosted environments, the `git` user is used for Git operations, and normal access to the server is granted by other users.  For example, if I wanted to push Git data, I'd authenticate as user `git`, but if I wanted to access the server as normal, I might authenticate as `bk2204`.  This is not true for GitHub, which uses a dedicated service to terminate Git SSH connections, but it may be true for other hosting environments, and is part of why the pattern is popular.